# Vue.directive calls twice if click up/down button

Tags: vue.js

Thanks in advance for the help guys...

I have got an input field for quantity  with Up and Down arrow
I don't want quantity to go negative.

I wrote a directive and if the user entered the minus number, it triggers once and set it zero but if the user clicks the up or down button just once, this calls the directive twice and the number goes up or down twice.

**VUE CODE**

```
Vue.directive('nonegative', function(el) {   
    const stockNoComma = el.value.replace(",", "");
    const stockQuantity = Number(stockNoComma);
    if (isNaN(stockQuantity)) {
        el.value="?";
    } else {
        if (stockQuantity < 0)
            el.value = "0";
    }
```

});

**HTML CODE**

```
<input v-model="product.quantity" v-nonegative class="form-control text-right" type="number" />
```

[JSFiddle Codes here](https://jsfiddle.net/adilsari/b56Lhtga/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)

A directive definition object can provide several hook functions (all optional):

- bind: called only once, when the directive is first bound to the element. This is where you can do one-time setup work.
  *inserted: called when the bound element has been inserted into its parent node (this only guarantees parent node presence, not necessarily in-document).
- update: called after the containing component’s VNode has updated, but possibly before its children have updated. The directive’s value may or may not have changed, **but you can skip unnecessary updates by comparing the binding’s current and old values** (see below on hook arguments).
- componentUpdated: called after the containing component’s VNode and the VNodes of its children have updated.
- unbind: called only once, when the directive is unbound from the element.

```js
Vue.directive('nonegative',{
    update: function(el, binding) {  
       if(binding.oldValue === bindign.value) return; 
       const stockNoComma = el.value.replace(",", "");
       const stockQuantity = Number(stockNoComma);
       if (isNaN(stockQuantity)) {
          el.value="?";
       } else {
          if (stockQuantity < 0)
            el.value = "0";
       }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Robert but still if I click the UP or DOWN button, the quantity increase or decreases twice again.

Comment: @AdilSari try with this return statement if value are the same.

Comment: Hi Robert, I put this code into JSFiddle and it seems working there but on my Browser(Google Chrome), it doesn't work, Vue Directive fires twice and not sure why. I edited question and add JSFiddle link now